# Trigger a release from a build queue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a release pipeline that triggers when there's a PR to master. I want to be able to trigger a release from a build queue (so without creating a pull request).

The proces now is to manually queue a build of a specific branch (this is fine):

[image: Step one]

Now I have to manually release the  branch as well:

[image]

I want to automate this proces.

Like I said my current automated release proces is only triggered when there's a PR for master:

[image]

Any suggestions how to trigger a release from a custom build action?

Comment: What do you mean by custom build action? Are you saying that you want the release to kick off no matter what build artifacts you have? If so, that would mean ANY branch build result. Are you sure that is something you want? I automate based on DEV or MASTER (with appropriate distribution and gates following) but not from feature branches.

Comment: In the build pipeline you can select a branch to create a build. See the first snippet in the question. The problem is that it's a not a merge to master. So my current release pipeline will not be triggered. Since it's only triggered on master.

What I want are feature branches. Say I'm changing the background of a element. I don't want that change to go in my dev/master/release (etc) branch unless my PO agrees to it. So I create a feature release. This release will deploy that artifact to a app service that's based on the branch name. This all works when creating a PR to master.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma do you have 1 release definition for all branches? if you run build `x` the same master release it's also for this build?

Comment: Currently I have 1 release definition for my master  branch. When I trigger a PR to master and complete the build the master branch will create a new release. During this release there's a task that creates a new app service based on the branch name.

Comment: If the release create a new app based on branch name so why the release trigger is only on master? configure the DC trigger to any branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger a release from inside the build - you can use Azure Devops rest api for that. This is the rest api call you are interested in:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0
```

you can use something like this to achieve that:

```
  $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${user}:$(PAT_TOKEN)"))
  $bearerAuth = @{ Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" }
Invoke-RestMethod POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0 -Headers $bearerAuth -ContentType "application/json" -Body xxx
```

Comment: How would I implement this? I'm using a YML file for my build.

Comment: use powershell step or script step

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose to add a source with Build as the artifact in Release, so you can trigger a release from a build queue without creating a pull request.The solution provided by 4c74356b41 is a good method, you can also try it.You can add a powershell task to the agent job of the build pipeline, and then write the script with the above rest api provided by4c74356b41 in the Inline script to run the build.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I would add: a build can be a release artifact + you can setup automatic trigger every time a new build artifact is available, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers

Comment: I can add a `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task to the build YML file to trigger a release as well.